# Raise, handle and note down the custom exceptions

Tags: c#, error-handling

I am creating a custom `Exception` class and trying to log the `CallerFilePath`, `CallerMemberName` and `CallerLineNumber` in the error log file along with the error message which is my main motive.

I am just wondering if it is a good way of doing this task or if there is a much better/cleaner way to raise/handle and note down the custom exceptions.

```
// Derive an exception with a specifiable message and inner exception. 
class DivisionException : Exception
{
   public DivisionException(string auxMessage) :
         base(auxMessage)
   { }

   public DivisionException(string auxMessage, Exception inner) :
        base(auxMessage, inner)
   { }

   public static String CreateMessage(string message,
        [CallerFilePath] string filePath = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string caller = null,
        [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
   {
     return string.Format("Exception: {0} Occured in File: {1} Function: {2} Line: {3}", 
                           message, filePath, caller, lineNumber);
   }
}

public static double Divide(int numerator, int denominator)
{
  try {
      return numerator / denominator;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    string message = DivisionException.CreateMessage("Division Failed");
    throw new DivisionException(message);
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
      int numerator = 100;
      int denominator = 0;
      double result = Divide(numerator, denominator);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
```

Comment: if your main motive is just noting down the caller Info, You dont need a separate class for that

Comment: so this isn't the actual code?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bit hard to review code like this because the code you are showing is example code rather than code that you're actually using in a real project, which means that a lot of context has been stripped away. Unlike Stack Overflow, we prefer to look at real code instead of example code. Please see the meta question: [Why is hypothetical code off-topic for Code Review?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Answer (score 3):

There are many things wrong with your division method... Consider the following:

> ```
> public static double Divide(int numerator, int denominator)
> {
>   try {
>       return numerator / denominator;
>   }
>   catch (Exception)
>   {
>     string message = DivisionException.CreateMessage("Division Failed");
>     throw new DivisionException(message);
>   }
> }
> ```

First up, numerator and denominator are great names, that's good, but they are also both `int` values....

You then return a `double`, but you use integer division first:

> ```
> return numerator / denominator;
> ```

That will, for example, return 0.0 for `1 / 2`..... which is not the double you are expecting.

Secondly, catching division-by-zero using exceptions is a poor way to do it. You should instead just pre-validate:

```
if (denominator == 0)
{
    string message = DivisionException.CreateMessage("Division Failed");
    throw new DivisionException(message);
}
```

then you don't need the try/catch, and also, your code is simpler, more standard-compliant, and easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are going about this all wrong.

you can catch the [`DivideByZeroException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and use the built in stack traces to give you all the information that you are trying to return. I don't see why you would create a brand new exception class.

At the least you should inherit the [`DivideByZeroException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception(v=vs.110).aspx) class and call your class something like `CustomDivideByZeroException` and add your method to the rest.

Comment: @Thanks Malachi, As I said My motive is to Note down caller information (from where this exception has been raised) and this is just an example, the real code is much more complex and not just "Divide by zero".